# Marketing Cloud Connector Objects not visible

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, connected-apps, tracking

I recently installed the marketing Cloud Connector and configured the connector as per salesforce documentation/trailhead module(https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect?trail_id=use-marketing-cloud-connect).
When I looked into the components of the package I noticed some objects that seems to be related to Journeys.

[image: Marketing Cloud Connector Components]

I tried looking for the objects in Object Manager or Schema Builder but only one object is visible (and holds 0 data)

[image: Object Manager Search]

Where can I see the other objects?

Is this some kind of retired functionality or a bug?

What I'm looking for is to see if any information about/from journeys is sent to Salesforce CRM (like the tracking data for Email Send, Individual Email result, etc.). Does anyone know?

Comment: Tracking data is sent from SFMC to Salesforce through BULK API and you will see it in the Individual Email Result and Individual Link Level Detail objects. According to the description, the MC CDC Journey object "shows the details of published Journeys that are dependent on CampaignId" but I've never used it for anything myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little late on this, but I thought it would be a good idea to give this one an answer in case someone will wander in here:

It seems that those are not Objects, but Platform Events created for communication between Salesforce CRM and Marketing Cloud and backend actions. This Events can be found in Setup -> Platform Events